# Hibernate mapping

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I was given a database with some existing data and I have to work on it with Hibernate without deleting the old data. My problem is that I have to insert a new child object and associate it with an existing parent object. I've worked already with hibernate but I've never faced a similar problem.

For example: Records already exist in the "STUDENT" table and now I want to create a "Project" object, save it, and associate with that student record. How should I handle this? Is removing the student reference (separate the two classes "no mapping") from the "Project" class and replacing it with a FK attribute a good approach?

the child class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PROJECT")
public class Project {

  @Id @GeneratedValue 
  @Column(name="ID")
  private int projectId;

  @Column(name="PROJECT_NAME")
  private String projectName;

  @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name="STUDENT_PROJECT")
  private Etudiant studentProject;

//getters and setters

}
```

the parent class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="STUDENT")
public class Student {
  @Id @GeneratedValue 
  @Column(name="ID")
  private int studentId;

  @Column(name="STUDENT_NAME")
  private String studentName;

  //getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are adding the PROJECT table you have the freedom to add the Foreign Key required to map to the STUDENT table. You have called this Foreign Key STUDENT_PROJECT, and used in you mapping;

```
  @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name="STUDENT_PROJECT")
  private Etudiant studentProject;
```

I assume Etudiant refers to the ***Student*** entity.

You have given this field the name of `studentProject` – but be clear that it is a `Student` and not a `Project`, I would call this just ‘student’.

In any case, this `studentProject` field holds an instance of the Student.

That looks fine. You do not need to modify the Student Table. You can add `Project` entities and they will be inserted and related to the existing `STUDENT` records.

I would be careful with the cascade=CascadeType.ALL, as removing the Project would cascade down the relationship and attempt to delete the Student which would probably not be desired and would result in FK constraint errors if the deleted Project had siblings, and you have set up your DB constriants correctly.

Additionally, you can make the relationship bidirectional by adding the following @OneToMany annotation in the `Student` entity

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy=" studentProject")
private Collection<Project> projects;

//getters and setters
```

> Is removing the student reference (separate the two classes "no
>   mapping") from the "Project" class and replacing it with a FK
>   attribute a good approach?

You must have some mapping if you want to persist your entities and relate them to each other. You can remove the need for a FK in either table by using a separate joinTable and that could also form the basis for a ManyToMany relationship should you want that. Plenty of references - try this to start.
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence